# Multiplexing data output

Tags: python, process

I'm continuosly reading an ADC for a project in Python.
I need to create to separate scripts to first: convert the results to an standard format and serving this data through internet over a protocol.

The point is I don't want the main program to stop getting data if anything happens to the other two processes and I need at the same time to serve the data gathered by the ADC to the other scripts.

What would be the best way to serve the data from the main program to these other two scripts? Creating an intermediate file or anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a typical use case for a queue. I would recommend to take a look at rabbitMq